# Linux How to change the Interrupt vector table device driver with my device driver?

Tags: linux, keyboard, kernel, driver, isr

I want to replace the keyboard device driver with my own device driver, that will just see if I pressed exit and if so will print the time (and if not, it will pass control to the normal device driver that I removed).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add some context: `If I press exit` : do you mean an exit button? (in which app?), or a specific keyboard key (on a regular 102 keys PC I do not see an "exit" key).

Comment: tried to add parenthesis and comma to better convey what I think was asked

Answer (score 0):

1. About changing vector table. It is not done by driver. Linux kernel setup interrupt vector table during booting system.
2. In linux a device is bound to a driver. If you want original driver not to work, you have to unload it and load your driver. Both can't work at same time. Also you need to build both drivers as loadable modules.